# Got null response body on Post retrofit2

Tags: android, response, retrofit2

i wanna make a post a to server, and get the response body to display it
but still always got the null string

this is my interface class

```
    @POST("peserta/cek")
    Call<CekPeserta> cekPeserta(@Body String kode_tiket);


   class Factory {

        private static PesertaAPI service;
        public static PesertaAPI getInstance(){

            if (service == null) {

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                service = retrofit.create(PesertaAPI.class);
                return service;
            }
            else return service;
        }
    }
```

and the mainClass

```
PesertaAPI.Factory.getInstance().cekPeserta("SDL8S3").enqueue(new Callback<CekPeserta>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CekPeserta> call, Response<CekPeserta> response) {
                Log.i("post status","sukses");
                Log.i("nama = ", String.valueOf(response.body().getName()));



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CekPeserta> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

its depend on what data accept by ur server if its `FormUrl` encoded then call like..

```
@POST("peserta/cek")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<CekPeserta> cekPeserta(@Body // your data );
```

and if its accept in `JSON Form` then call like..

```
@POST("peserta/cek")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
Call<CekPeserta> cekPeserta(@Body // your data);
```

for more info.. and detail [click-here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)